# Подключение оплаты через сбербанк к сайту

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WP, без WooCommerce(т.е. каких-то готовых плагинов нет). Необходимо подключить самую простую оплату сбербанк. Поискал в их документациях, но ничего толкового не нашел.
Может кто-то сталкивался с этим? У кого-нибудь есть решение этой задачи?

Comment: *но ничего толкового не нашел* - каковы критерии толковости?

Comment: если ничего не нашли, м.б. WooCommerce ?

Comment: А Вы думаете, Сбербанк так просто Вам даст на непонятно каком сайте платежи принимать? )) Там сперва заявку заполнить придётся: http://www.sberbank.ru/ru/s_m_business/bankingservice/internet_acquiring

Comment: @Alex, WooCommerce не совсем подходит, т.к. тема нестандартная(делаю сайт объявлений) и уже имеет форму оплаты , но без модуля от сбербанк

Comment: @humster_spb, так я и не против) просто пока не могу настроить механизм оплаты

Comment: @r.mcreal, так Вы начните с заявки, а там уже и техническая поддержка от Сбера подтянется

Comment: Или сразу Яндекс.Кассу подключайте

Answer (score 6):

> Необходимо подключить самую простую оплату сбербанк.

Сам сбербанк РФ далеко не каждый сайт подключит. См [тут](http://www.sberbank.ru/ru/s_m_business/bankingservice/internet_acquiring) внимательно:

[image: Документы, договор]

Поэтому для простых решений проще использовать агрегаторы (я.касса и тп) и/или вот типа таких плагинов: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/leyka/